# Uploading a file in Java Play 1.2.3 then storing file as byte array causes PersistenceException

Tags: exception, file-upload, h2, playframework-1.x

I'm creating a POST service that allows an admin-user to upload images to a Play! application, and while I'm testing it I am using the inbuilt H2 filesystem database.  According to

https://gist.github.com/1256286#file-picture-java-L3

a good way to store these images in Play! is as a byte array, which is then rendered using `Controller#renderBinary(...)`.

The `Campaign` object in this function stores all the data about a campaign and has a list of `Banner` objects, each of which is basically an image file and some metadata.  The following method under a custom `Controller` is supposed to receive images for upload:

```
public static void putCampaignBanner (Upload bannerFile) {
    Campaign campaign = findCampaignByIdOrNew();

    if(campaign.banners == null) {
        campaign.banners = new LinkedList<Banner>();
    }

    String name = params.get("name", String.class);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bannerFile.asFile());
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //it's not a picture.  die gracefully.
        e.printStackTrace();
        renderJSON(new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create().toJson(campaign));
        return;
    }
    if(name==null||name.length()==0) {
        //no name.  die gracefully.  like a swan.
        renderJSON(new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create().toJson(campaign));
        return;
    }

    Banner banner=null;

    for(Banner b: campaign.banners) {
        if(b.name.equals(name)) {
            banner = b;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(banner==null) {
        banner=new Banner();
        banner.name=name;
        banner.campaign = campaign;
        banner.save();
        campaign.banners.add(banner);
    }

    //validate file and populate banner

    //__ vv THIS LINE CAUSES THE EXCEPTION__
    banner.file = bannerFile.asBytes();
    //__ ^^ REMOVING THIS LINE PREVENTS THE EXCEPTION__

    banner.contenttype = bannerFile.getContentType();
    banner.width = width;
    banner.height = height;
    banner.url = getRouterUrlWithId("ImageService.getById", banner.id);

    //__ vv THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION__
    campaign.save();
    banner.save();

    renderJSON(new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create().toJson(campaign));

}
```

I'm waiting for another developer to complete the upload form so I am testing this using curl:

```
curl http://[ourserver]:9000/TemplatePopulationController/putCampaignBanner -i -F campaignPrimaryId=44 -F name=headerBanner -F bannerFile=@tempimages/pissybiscuit.png
```

Obviously I need to store the image.  How can I prevent the PersistenceException?

UPDATE
I have tried adding the @Lob annotation to the `byte[]` and also changing the argument type to `Blob` and persisting the object thus.  Neither has worked.

Examining the logs showed that the server experienced a GenericJDBCException with:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "c73e69c8-3443-489a-b5f0-ef40af99673f|image/jpeg";
```

The log for an instance of the error is:

```
@6d0npdn4l
Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /TemplatePopulationController/putCampaignBanner

Execution exception (In /app/controllers/TemplatePopulationController.java around line 285)
PersistenceException occured : update Banner set campaign_id=?, file=?, height=?, name=?, url=?, width=? where id=?

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: update Banner set campaign_id=?, file=?, height=?, name=?, url=?, width=? where id=?
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:229)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: update Banner set campaign_id=?, file=?, height=?, name=?, url=?, width=? where id=?
    at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:50)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:184)
    at controllers.TemplatePopulationController.putCampaignBanner(TemplatePopulationController.java:285)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
    ... 1 more
16:06:36,553 INFO  ~ campaignPrimaryId=8
16:06:36,571 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 90003, SQLState: 90003
16:06:36,571 ERROR ~ Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "363438fc-f232-401e-9f69-7db499a24ba4|application/octet-stream"; SQL statement: update Banner set campaign_id=?, file=?, height=?, name=?, url=?, width=? where id=? [90003-170]
16:06:36,572 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 90003, SQLState: 90003
16:06:36,572 ERROR ~ Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "363438fc-f232-401e-9f69-7db499a24ba4|application/octet-stream"; SQL statement: update Banner set campaign_id=?, file=?, height=?, name=?, url=?, width=? where id=? [90003-170]
16:06:36,572 ERROR ~ Could not synchronize database state with session org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException (SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:795)
    at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:47)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:184)
    at controllers.TemplatePopulationController.putCampaignBanner(TemplatePopulationController.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:220)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:265)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "363438fc-f232-401e-9f69-7db499a24ba4|application/octet-stream"; SQL statement: update Banner set campaign_id=?, file=?, height=?, name=?, url=?, width=? where id=? [90003-170]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:1121)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 29 more
16:06:36,591 ERROR ~

@6d0npdn4m
Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /TemplatePopulationController/putCampaignBanner

Execution exception (In /app/controllers/TemplatePopulationController.java around line 285)
PersistenceException occured : update Banner set campaign_id=?, file=?, height=?, name=?, url=?, width=? where id=?

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: update Banner set campaign_id=?, file=?, height=?, name=?, url=?, width=? where id=?
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:229)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: update Banner set campaign_id=?, file=?, height=?, name=?, url=?, width=? where id=?
    at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:50)
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:184)
    at controllers.TemplatePopulationController.putCampaignBanner(TemplatePopulationController.java:285)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message and all stack traces.

Comment: I've added the stack traces I got.  The error page really just repeats the information from the stack traces.

Comment: This seems possibly relevant: http://www.lunatech-research.fr/playframework-file-upload-blob

Comment: Although more so to the `Blob` approach.  I'd forgotten I was using a different approach when I started this.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a problem in the interaction between Play and H2.  I am indebted to this article for part of the answer:

http://www.lunatech-research.fr/playframework-file-upload-blob

It seems Play! doesn't actually put a `Blob` object into the database as a Binary Large OBject, but instead stores it as a file in a folder called "attachments" (whose path is configurable).  The files in this folder all have UUIDs as filenames, and in fact one I looked at rendered as a `.png` I attempted to upload through my service.  What Play! then stores in the database is the filename and content type, eg

```
c73e69c8-3443-489a-b5f0-ef40af99673f|image/jpeg
```

Here, though, `c73e69c8-3443-489a-b5f0-ef40af99673f` is not a hexadecimal number but a filename.  H2 may be assuming it *is* a hexadecimal number and trying to convert it, or Play! may be invoking H2 such that it *expects* a hexadecimal number stored as a `String`.  Either way, Play! isn't actually storing a `Blob` as a SQL BLOB, and the `String` it is trying to store instead is being interpreted as a hexadecimal value.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "c73e69c8-3443-489a-b5f0-ef40af99673f|image/jpeg";
```

Switching the Play! database to a MySQL database (which was planned post-testing anyway) made it work.  I am not sure if this can be fixed while still using H2 *without actually rewriting H2 or Play*, but if anyone knows a fix I will mark that as the answer.

Comment: This is definitely not a bug within H2. Instead, it seems the Play framework tries to store a blob as text, instead of an input stream, when using H2.

Comment: Adjusted the answer to match your comment.  I'd argue that trying to persist a string as a hex binary value because it looks like it might be one is a misfeature, though.